# Do I always have to do a reality check when doing probability problems?

Tags: combinatorics

Mathematically speaking, the possibility of A and B both happening is P(A) • P(B).

For example, event A is that the numbers on two dice thrown is equal to 7. And event B is that at least one die has a 6. Thus:
A={(1,6),(6,1),(2,5),(5,2),(3,4),(4,3)}
B={(1,6),(2,6),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,6),(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5)}

From this, we know P(A)=1/6, and P(B)=11/36 and that P(both A and B)=2/36. But the product of P(B) and P(A) is not equal to P(A and B) if we are to list everything out.

**Example 2**, say we choose two independent events and do the same reality check. This time event A is that the sum of two dice is equal to 4. And event B, same, is that at least one dice is 6. 
A={(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)}
Multiply P(A) and P(B), 3/36 * 11/36= 33/216. But the true answer is 0.

**example 3**  what is the probability of drawing a spade or a king from a deck of 52 cards? P(a spade)=13/52=1/4 P(a king)=4/52=1/13

P(a king or a spade)=P(A) + P(B) -P(A and B if they are not independent)

Again mathematically P(A and B) is 1/52. But this time realistically, P(A and B) is indeed 1/52 (the king of spades).

**Do we need to check our mathematically-obtained answer with reality to ensure its correctness?**

Comment: In probability theory, the word "independent" does not mean what you seem to think it means. In Example 2, I assume that you ***meant*** event A to be, "the numbers on the two dice ***add up** to 4", or in other words, "the ***sum*** of the numbers on the two dice is 4."  You wrote something different, namely, "the two dice ***are equal*** to 4", meaning that you rolled (4,4). In either case, the events A and B are ***not*** independent.

Comment: I think I am confusing independent with mutual exclusive

Comment: Yes, you are confusing independent with mutually exclusive, which is kind of llike confusing hot with cold or up with down. "Mutually exclusive" is almost the ***opposite*** of independent, so they should not be confused.

Comment: @bot Though experience shows that it is somewhat *routine* for students to do so.  Sigh.

Comment: To answer your title: If you are a perfect person and never make mistakes, then you don't have to check your results. On the other hand, if you're like me and make lots of mistakes, then it might be a good idea to check your results any way you can.

Comment: @bof, if there is a green die and a white die, should (6,6) or just (n,n) be counted twice in the sample space? ('Cause, u know 6 on the green and 6 on the white are different. But my book only counts twice (n,k) twice)

Comment: (6,6) should be counted just once. Because "6 on the green die" is indeed different from "6 on the white die", but "6 on the green die and 6 on the white die" is ***the same*** as "6 on the white die and 6 on the green die".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mathematically speaking, the possibility of A and B both happening is P(A) • P(B).

ONLY if they are *independent* events.

> *Example 2*, say we choose two independent events and do the same reality check. This time event A is that the two dice are equal to 4. And event B, same, is that at least one dice is 6. A={(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)} Multiply P(A) and P(B), 3/36 * 11/36= 33/216. But the true answer is 0.

These are clearly *not* independent events.   They are in fact *mutually exclusive* events (also known as *disjoint* events).   For such events $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0$.

---

Events are independent if the occurrence of one event has no influence on the probability of occurrence of another event.   Then $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\cdot P(B)$

More generally, one event will have a conditional probability given the occurrence of another event.   Then we have $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B\mid A)$

**Example** Let $A$ be the event that a die result is even, and let $B$ be the event that it is three or less.   We have $\mathsf P(A)=1/2$ and $\mathsf P(B)=1/2$, but clearly the events are *not* independent as under the condition that the die result is even the probability that it is less than three is $1/3$.   (Only 1 of the 3 even results is three or less).    That is $\mathsf P(B\mid A) = 1/3$.

So the probability that the result is both even *and* three or less, is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cap B) & = \mathsf P(A)\cdot \mathsf P(B\mid A) \\ & = \tfrac 1 6 & \neq \tfrac 1 4\end{align}$$

Since $A\cap B$ is the event that the result is two, this is as it should be.

---

**tl;dr** No, $\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \mathsf P(A)\cdots\mathsf P(B)$ *only* in the specific case where the events are *independent*.   It is *not* a general result.   So you *do* have to pay attention to reality (or at least to your experiment's theoretical *model* of reality).

Comment: "Independent and dependent" are used when you want both happen at the SAME TIME. "Mutual exclusive" is for OR case, where just one happens?

Comment: @Doeser Yes.  *Mutually exclusive* events are those which can not happen simultaneously.  *Independent* events are those which do not influence each other's probability - so: $\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(A\mid B)$  *Dependent* events are those which are not independent (this includes mutually exclusive events, which are very dependent.)

Comment: But I thought mutually exclusive has nothing to do dependent. Since they don't have same time frame

Comment: Mutually exclusive mean P(A and B) is 0? I don't see how they are dependent if they have nothing in common.

Comment: What "time frame"?  *Dependent* events are those where the condition of one event occurring *influences* the probability that the other event also occurs.  *Mutually exclusive* events are those where the condition of one event occurring *prohibits* the occurrence of the other event.  That is a significant influence.

Comment: I have this question. What is the probability of getting a head or a 4, when a die and a coin is flipped. They are mutually exclusive. But the answer is not 3/6+1/6=2/3 but 7/12. Why?

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive, @Doeser , they are *independent*.  The coin toss does not influence the outcome of the die roll. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C{=}h\cup D{=}4) & = \mathsf P(C{=}h)+\mathsf P(D{=}4)-\mathsf P(C{=}h\cap D{=}4) \\[1ex] & = \frac 1 2+\frac 1 6 - \frac 1{12} \\[1ex] & = \frac 7{12}\end{align}$$